# how to change arraylist to hashmap object?

Tags: json, hashmap

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap<String, BeanClass> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("First", beanclass1);
hm.put("Second", beanclass2);
hm.put("Third", beanclass3);
hm.put("Fourth", beanclass4);
hm.put("Fifth", beanclass5);

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add(hm);

String st = gson.toJson(al);
System.out.println(st);

ArrayList al2 = gson.fromJson(st, ArrayList.class);

System.out.println(al2);

//  HashMap hm1= (HashMap) al2.get(0);

 // System.out.println(hm1);
```

How to convert arraylist to hashmap? here hm is hashmap. Then 
      converted to arraylist (al). Then al is convertd to al2 arrayobject .Finally, how to al2 arrayobject to hashmap object?

```
error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

Comment: reply soon man..here problegoing on..

Comment: Please, edit you question, you probably messed up with formatting.

Comment: no man..how to convert arraylist to hashmap?

Comment: HashMap<String, BeanClass> hm2 = (HashMap<String, BeanClass>) al2.get(0);
        //  System.out.println(hm2);
        Set<String> key = hm2.keySet();
        Iterator it = key.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String hmkey = (String) it.next();
            BeanClass hmvalue = (BeanClass) hm2.get(hmkey);

            System.out.println("Key: " + hmkey + " & Value: " + hmvalue);this is right or wrong?..i goot error class cast exception

Comment: response immediate..guys